# How do you rename the groupID of an imported Maven package to remove a hyphen?

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, apache-flink

I am working through [this Apache Flink training](https://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/dataStream/1-handsOn.html) where you create a simple application to reads data from a file and filters it. I am using Scala as the language to write the Flink application, and the final code looks like this:

```
package com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_scala.basics

import com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_java.sources.TaxiRideSource
import com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_java.utils.GeoUtils
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._

object RideCleansing {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)
    val input = params.getRequired("input")

    val maxDelay = 60
    val speed = 600 

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

    val rides = env.addSource(new TaxiRideSource(input, maxDelay, speed))

    val filteredRides = rides
      .filter(r => GeoUtils.isInNYC(r.startLon, r.startLat) && GeoUtils.isInNYC(r.endLon, r.endLat))

    filteredRides.print()
    env.execute("Taxi Ride Cleansing")
  }

}
```

As recommended [here](https://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/devEnvSetup.html), I've added the following to my POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.data-artisans</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-training-exercises</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I type `maven clean package`, however, I get the following error:

```
error: object dataartisans is not a member of package com
import com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_java.sources.TaxiRideSource
```

It seems to be looking for the package `com.dataartisans`, but it was imported as `com.data-artisans` with a hyphen, so it cannot find it. How do I resolve this issue if my main IDE is IntelliJ?

Here is the output from the `package` command:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Flink Quickstart Job 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ flink-scala-project ---
[INFO] Deleting /da-flink/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ flink-scala-project ---
[INFO] Source directory: /da-flink/src/main/scala added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ flink-scala-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ flink-scala-project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default) @ flink-scala-project ---
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.4 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.10:1.3.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.10:1.3.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.4 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.scalamacros:quasiquotes_2.10:2.0.1 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.10:1.3.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.10:1.3.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.10:1.3.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.data-artisans:flakka-actor_2.10:2.3-custom requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.data-artisans:flakka-remote_2.10:2.3-custom requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.data-artisans:flakka-slf4j_2.10:2.3-custom requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  org.clapper:grizzled-slf4j_2.10:1.0.2 requires scala version: 2.10.3
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] /da-flink/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /da-flink/target/classes at 1498877506263
[ERROR] /da-flink/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/quickstart/RideCleansing.scala:21: error: object dataartisans is not a member of package com
[ERROR] import com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_java.sources.TaxiRideSource
[ERROR]            ^
[ERROR] /da-flink/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/quickstart/RideCleansing.scala:22: error: object dataartisans is not a member of package com
[ERROR] import com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_java.utils.GeoUtils
[ERROR]            ^
[ERROR] /da-flink/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/quickstart/RideCleansing.scala:61: error: not found: type TaxiRideSource
[ERROR]     val rides = env.addSource(new TaxiRideSource(input, maxDelay, servingSpeed))
[ERROR]                                   ^
[ERROR] three errors found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.077 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-30T22:51:48-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default) on project flink-scala-project: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out  to be very simple: I put the dependency in the wrong section of the pom file, with another group of dependencies that were part of a profile. Careless mistake...

Answer (score 2):

`groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` (a.k.a. *GAV*) are [*Maven coordinates*](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) which are essential to identify an artifact (`jar`) both logically (in a POM) and physically (in a repository). This has nothing to do with packages inside the artifact or imports inside the class files in the artifact. GAV are there to access them from a repository to build up a proper class path. So "*but it was imported as `com.data-artisans`*" is not a correct statement in this respect. Hence the issue must be somewhere else but at Maven.

BTW, at which build phase does the error occur? I guess it's `compile`, is it? Supplying more related lines of the build output usually makes things clearer.

Where did you get version `0.10.0` from? It's not available at [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.data-artisans%22%20AND%20a%3A%22flink-training-exercises%22). I suggest to give version `0.6` from there a try.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I added the output above. 0.10.0 is from the guide itself, but perhaps that's incorrect? https://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/devEnvSetup.html

Comment: As part of the setup it had us download and install the project directly from GitHub, and it looks like that version is 0.10.0: https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: @Brideau If I access the `<repository>/<url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/` from there in my browser I get: "_Access Denied – Please login before attempting further requests._".

Comment: Found the issue (see other response). Turned out it was a really simple mistake.